# How to use custom manager with related objects?

Tags: django, django-managers, django-orm

I have a custom manager. I want to use it for related objects. I found   [use_for_related_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-typesin) in docs. But it does not work the way I used it:

```
class RandomQueryset(models.query.QuerySet):

    def randomize(self):       
        count = self.count()
        random_index = random.randint(0, count - 1)
        return self.all()[random_index]


class RandomManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        return RandomQueryset(self.model, using=self._db)

    def randomize(self):
        return self.get_query_set().randomize()
```

I used it for one model:

```
>>> post = PostPages.default_manager.filter(image_gallery__isnull=False).distinct().randomize()
```

And tried to do the same with m2m related object:

```
>>> post.image_gallery.randomize()
```

Got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'randomize'
```

Is it possible to use a custom manager in the way I did it? If so, how do you make it work?

## Edit

My models:

```
class ShivaImage(models.Model, ImageResizing):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    slide_show = models.BooleanField() 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = RandomManager()


class PostPages(models.Model):
    image_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(ShivaImage, blank=True,
                                       related_name='gallery',)
    # all the other fields... 

    objects = RandomManager()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

***THIS IS ONLY SUGGESTED FOR Django 1.09 or older*** - [Docs proof](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#manager-use-for-related-fields-and-inheritance-changes)

Setting `use_for_related_fields` to `True` on the manager will make it available on all relations that point *to* the model on which you defined this manager as the default manager. This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#manager-types)

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True
    # ...
```

I suppose you have it only enabled on your `PostPages` model, not on your `Gallery` model (or whatever the model is called that is referenced through `post_image_gallery`). If you want to have additionally functionality on this realtion manager you need to add a custom default manager with `use_for_related_fields = True` to your `Gallery` model!

Comment: I defined the manager in both models. If I right understood, `objects` is means default manager. See question edits, I added models in there.

Comment: The _first_ manager defined becomes the default manager, no matter if it's called `objects` or not...

Comment: Uoo hooo! It's works! Most likely there was some very stupid mistake. Because now it's ok.

Comment: Warning, as of Django 1.10 this feature is deprecated in favor of setting Meta.base_manager_name on the model. See release notes in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#manager-use-for-related-fields-and-inheritance-changes.

Comment: Other warning: the docs also says that managers aren't used when querying on related objects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager. This prevents from using that feature to filter out related objects implicitely.

Comment: @DavidGuillot: Thanks. Any idea how to work around that related object query restriction? Do you know what is used instead of managers?

Answer (score 49):

For completeness of the topic, Django 1.7 (finally) supports [using a custom reverse manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-custom-reverse-manager), so you can do something like that (just copying from the django docs):

```
from django.db import models

class Entry(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()  # Default Manager
    entries = EntryManager()    # Custom Manager

b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
b.entry_set(manager='entries').all()
```

Answer (score 21):

In django 2.0 `use_for_related_fields` is deprecated https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/#manager-use-for-related-fields-and-inheritance-changes

You should use `base_manager_name`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.base_manager_name

Updated docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
    special_manager = MyManager()

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'special_manager'
```

Comment: `base_manager_name` expects the name of the manager in question as a a string, not the instance. See [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8dc675d90f14a84ef95f16c7cc8100d9a04459b3/tests/custom_managers/models.py#L158).

Comment: for me, setting `base_manager_name` was even necessary when overrding default `objects` attribute in my model (before, I thought this would only be needed if manager name differs from default `objects`)!

Answer (score 1):

Also, in the custom manager, make sure to access the queryset via the self.get_query_set()
proxy method when implementing custom filters to be called from related manager:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def visible_events(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        # don't do this !!! 
        # unsuitable for related managers as could retrieve extraneous objects
        # qs = super(EventManager, self).get_query_set()
        # Use queryset proxy method as follows, instead:
        qs = self.get_query_set()
        qs = qs.filter(visible_from__lte=today, visible_to__gte=today)
        return qs


class Event(models.Model):

    visible_from = models.DateField(_(u'visible from'), null=False, blank=False)
    visible_to = models.DateField(_(u'visible to'), null=False, blank=False)
    concepts = models.ManyToManyField(Concept, through='ConceptEventRegistration')

    objects = EventManager()
```

Sample usage:

```
my_concept = Concept.objects.get(id=1)
# retrieve all events related to the object
my_concept.event_set.all()
# retrieve all visible events related to the object
my_concept.event_set.visible_events()
```