# Using custom Manager & QuerySet does not work with related objects properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

Given two simple models:

```
class Employee(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class AttendanceLog(Model):
    from_datetime = models.DateTimeField(_('from'))
    to_datetime = models.DateTimeField(_('to'))
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('employee'))
```

We can retrieve `some_employee`'s attendance logs just fine: `some_employee.attendancelog_set`. We can also use custom queryset in attendance log (`objects = AttendanceLogQuerySet.as_manager()`), such as:

```
class AttendanceLogQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def today(self):
        # returns logs that has to_datetime with today's date.
        return self.filter(
            to_datetime__date=date.today()
        )
```

And so we can retrieve employee's attendance for today by doing:`some_employee.attendancelog_set.today()`

The problem is when we try to use both custom Manager and custom Queryset (`objects = AttendanceLogManager()`), such as:

```
class AttendanceLogQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def today(self):
        # returns logs that has to_datetime with today's date.
        return self.filter(
            to_datetime__date=datetime.today()
        )

class AttendanceLogManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AttendanceLogQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def some_special_create_method(self, some_args):
        pass
```

We get an error:
`AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'today'`

This should work according to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) on how to use both QuerySet and a Manager.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124863/3627387

Comment: Even with adding `use_for_related_fields = True`, the error is raised. (I use 1.1.9 version so it is not yet depreciated)

Answer (score 0):

In your class AttendanceLogManager, you should define :

```
def today(self):
    return self.get_queryset().today()
```

After that in your class AttendanceLog(Model) you need to declare :

```
objects = AttendanceLogManager()
```

I found [this link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/16/django-tip-11-custom-manager-with-chainable-querysets.html) very helpful