# How to I automatically filter out is_deleted records in an associated table in Django?

Tags: django

I am using soft deletes on one of my models in Django, and I am overwriting the default manager to always return active records only, using something like:

```
class ActiveRecordManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)

class Tag(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    objects = ActiveRecordManager()

class Photo(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="photos")
    objects = ActiveRecordManager()
```

All works well. However, when I do:

```
tag = Tag.objects.get(pk=100)
```

And then I try to get the associated photos:

```
photos = tag.photos.all()
```

Then I get photos that are deleted. I only want to return objects that are *not* deleted (so my regular *objects* list. I was reading about _base_mangers in Django, which seems to control this, but [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager) recommends against filtering objects out:

> If you override the get_queryset() method and filter out any rows,
>   Django will return incorrect results. Don’t do that. A manager that
>   filters results in get_queryset() is not appropriate for use as a base
>   manager.

But what I am not clear about is how I *am* supposed to filter these results. Any thoughts?

UPDATE:

I was asked to explain how this question is different from this one:
[How to use custom manager with related objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489635/how-to-use-custom-manager-with-related-objects)

In this 8 year old question they mention a deprecated method. That deprecated method is superseded by the method I outline below (base_managers) which according to the documentation I should *not* use. If people think I should use it, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use custom manager with related objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489635/how-to-use-custom-manager-with-related-objects)

Comment: Are you using any Queryset class too? or just a manager?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu in that post they talk about use_for_related_fields, but this is deprecated and instead base_manager_name should be used. But as I explained in my post according to the documentation I should not be using that in my case. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ArunT I am not sure what a Queryset class is. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not use custom query methods instead of overriding manager as it may produce problems for example in admin pages?

```py
class ActiveModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def not_active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(is_deleted=True, *args, **kwargs)

    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(is_deleted=False, *args, **kwargs)


class Tag(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    objects = ActiveModelQuerySet().as_manager()

class Photo(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="photos")
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    objects = ActiveModelQuerySet().as_manager()
```

you can then filter your models however you want

```
tag = Tag.objects.active(pk=100)

deleted_tags = Tag.objects.not_active()

photos = tag.photos.active()
```

also note that you need `is_deleted` attribute in all your models that have the soft delete functionality like `Photo` in your case

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of this particular way of doing things!